# What heading should be written in a resume instead of "Technical Expertise" when I am not an "expert"?

Tags: resume

> **Technical Expertise:**

```
Languages & Frameworks:       C, C++, Qt
Development tools:            GCC, GDB, Valgrind, SVN
OS:                           Linux (OpenSUSE)
Concepts::                    UML, Design patterns, Socket programming, Data structures
```

This is a sample from my example resume.

I ***know*** these subjects but I cannot say that I am an ***expert*** in these subjects. I do not want to mislead the interviewer by the fancy words like "Technical Expertise".

I want him to question me but not like as if I am a God or a super man!
**What heading should be written instead of "Technical Expertise" when I am not an "expert"?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Experience would be the most obvious choice.  This way all you are implying is that you have used these technologies and could have varying levels of skill.

Skill would also work as you are identifying specific areas though this doesn't always work as some software may not be seen as a skill.

Proficiencies would be a more formalized term if you wanted something a bit more exotic than experience.

Comment: "Technical Experience" indeed doesn't sound "Godly". Thanks.

Comment: 'Experience' is usually taken to mean time spent doing something, and is not the same as expertize. It is possible to have a high level of expertize but little experience, or vica versa. Not that I'm saying I prefer expertize over experience...

Answer (score 2):

No the original heading is fine. I think your over thinking this in English "expertize" (or expertise if you don't use the OED) can also mean  "Skill or knowledge in a particular area" - This is the sense that it is always used in CV's and resumes.

I might say I have expertize in TCP/IP doesn't meant that I am claiming CCIE level understanding

Comment: I'm not sure whether to vote this down or not (I haven't), as I agree with the OP that "expertise" refers specifically to an *expert* level of skill, knowledge or experience - see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expertise .

Comment: This answer is right. You can have a 'low level of expertize', meaning you are not an expert at something.

Comment: +Mark Banister no its not look up the defination in a dictionary

Comment: @Neuro: look at the link in my previous comment - you will see it is a dictionary reference. It is also bad practise to refer another user to a dictionary in a sentence that displays poor spelling and punctuation.

Comment: I think the word "expertise" might create a communication gap when the interviewer is a non-native English speaker!?!

Comment: +Anisha Kaul then why would the CV be in English? using english in non standard ways or using creole or variant english dialects is going to get your CV marked down or discarded.

Comment: @Neuro you haven't been to India, it seems! ;)

Comment: +Anisha Kaul well should have tagged it as country specific :-) even so I suspect that the OED is still considered a definitive source in India just as its is in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Technical recruiter here that has seen many thousands of resumes, and I've never seen "Technical Expertise" used on a resume (I'm in the US).  The most accepted sections for that title would be either "Skills", "Technical Skills", "Technologies", or "Technical Experience".

Comment: Hi Fecak. Thank you for sharing your experiences. Can you please tell us *why* these terms you list are better?

Comment: Jmort253 - I never said they were better. If you read my comment, I said I had never seen the term Expertise used, and that the terms I listed were most accepted (common might be more accurate). Expertise, as was stated earlier, may come across as somewhat vain, and having 'expertise' with a technology is different than having 'experience' or exposure. If you use 'Expertise', you might be more reluctant to list a technology that you have light exposure to, but you could list more liberally if you refer to 'Experience' or 'Skill' (skill has a wide implied range).

Comment: Hi Fecak, sorry, I wasn't trying to put words in your mouth, but I suggest putting your explanation from the above comment in your answer as it does help support it even more. In short, it would help ensure your post is more of an answer than just a comment. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No offense taken.  However, if you reread the question posed (What heading should be written...), what I provided was absolutely a very direct and complete answer to the question posed (list of accepted terms) and not just a comment.

Comment: Hi Fecak, I do think you brought up good points in your answer, and I personally don't plan to take any action on this post, but our [faq] *does* say that "answers should be backed up either with a reference, or experiences that happened to you personally. You should always include in your answer information about why you think your answer is correct."  I don't want to debate whether or not you've done that here, but I do know that if you add the info from your comment to the answer, there will be less to debate with others, and your answer will be more likely to get upvoted. Good luck! :)